# Insert cache in module

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a cache to my custom phtml page.

I built a module that show a custom PHP page. But that code will not cache default by Magento cache. I need to add it, but I don't now how and I can not find the answer on the internet.

The page will show right, but very very slow, so thats why I need to cache it.

My module looks like this:

```
 app/code/Absolute/AdvancedSlider/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
 app/code/Absolute/AdvancedSlider/Block/Slider.php
 app/code/Absolute/AdvancedSlider/view/frontend/templates/slider.phtml
```